# i want to restrict all users except root from copying,deleting and browing the file is that possible

Tags: linux, permissions, operating-system, file-permissions

I want to restrict all users except root from copying,deleting and browsing the file is that possible and if the user wants to copy the file he has to be prompted with the authentication
please help me with this

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to restrict all users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017919/i-want-to-restrict-all-users)

Comment: please don't post multiple time the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for.

1) Create the file logged in as root

2) Run this on it

```
chmod 700 file
```